# Jenkins polls a wrong branch

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have configured my branch for a Pipelines project like this:

`*/master`

However, according to the Git poll log:

> [poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/ci_test is:
>   c945253a1f3aed6be113347e37aa3512db43bcf0 - already built by 17 Done.
>   Took 11 sec No changes

It always tries to poll `ci_test` that was the branch I initially tested with. Same thing with BitBucket webhook. It reacts only on the `ci_test` branch despite that fact that only `master` is now configured, applied and saved. I also tried to restart Jenkins with no luck.

Any ideas how to debug this?

Edit: If I trigger the build manually it builds `master`. The poller still polls `ci_test` no matter what. Wtf?

Edit2: Setting the branch to any (leave blank) fails to fetch anything even manually.

Comment: Did you tried to re-create webhook?

Comment: can you share you pipeline code so i can help ? or screen shot at least?

Answer (score 4):

The solution that worked for me was:

- Delete all configuration related to polling (trigger clause in the pipeline, polling configuration in the job)
- Run a build manually (it should build the correct branch)
- Restore polling configuration

After these changes, polling restarted and began to query the correct branch.

Comment: Deleting and readding the configuration worked in my case.

Comment: This worked for me but ONLY if the manual build completes with success. If I abort the manual build in between (which I few times) the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

The "solution" was to move on to a Multibranch Pipelines project. The legacy Pipelines project seems to be confusing and broken with multiple branches anyway:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46588

Additionally the webhook might also be somehow buggy, but this multi-branch project type seems to be working much better.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that I had specified "Branch Specifier" as */* and changing that to empty value fixed the problem, as instructed: (blank for 'any').

Probably for you case you should put 'master' instead of */master

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that the problem is with webhook on BitBucket, not with Jenkins configuration. Probably webhook was created for `ci_test` branch and now doesn't see the changes for `master` branch.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue (our Jenkins server hasn't been updated for a couple of years, so pretend the date on this post is 2017).  I believe it's because of this bug (I believe both are the same problem):

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50168

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55524

I don't have a solution, although I'll update this answer if the multi-branch pipeline works.

Answer (score 0):

Be  sure that you don't have enabled the **[Lightweight checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNjSv.png)** checkbox in the Pipeline section.

Unfortunately, it's not compatible to Bitbucket webhook plugin..